# How to include urls when evoking ActionMailer::Base.mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am sending an email with Rails like so:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  from: "me@example.com",
  to: "you@example.com",
  subject: "test",
  body: "test"
).deliver
```

I want the body to include `[test](https://ham.com)`, but this markdown is not parsed, and `<a href="https://ham.com">test</a>` doesn't work either.

How can I format my url so it gets formatted properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it sent as HTML then you need to provide the `Content-Type` header (`content_type: "text/html"`), although it's better to follow the normal approach of a mailer subclass, and using templates.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Yes the templates are best for most cases, but these are super one off and time is of the essence